# unix shell script - search string and formatting to json

Tags: json, shell, unix

I have a log file with multiple json message that is not formatted.
Trying to write a shell script to search for a string in the logs and format the matching json and write to a file.

For Example :- in the test.log file,

> type_logfile 2015-04-14 18:06:15,284 INFO ResponseLogService -
>   {"header":{"time":"2015 06:06:13 PM EDT","reqId":"1","user":"baskar"}}
>
> type_logfile 2015-04-14 18:06:15,284 INFO ResponseLogService -
>   {"header":{"time":"2015 06:06:13 PM EDT","reqId":"2","user":"raja"}}
>
> type_logfile 2015-04-14 18:06:15,284 INFO ResponseLogService -
>   {"header":{"time":"2015 06:06:13 PM EDT","reqId":"3","user":"baskar"}}

I use the below command,

```
grep -i "baskar" test.log | grep -o "{\"header\".*" | python -m json.tool > ~/search_result.log
```

The above command works fine if the search returns only one json message. If there are multiple matches, this doesnt work and throw the following error.

Unable to decode the json message.

Whereas, if i redirect the matched output to some file and then read the file line by line to format the json works.

```
 grep -i "baskar" test.log | grep -o "{\"header\".*" > ~/search_result.log

while read line
do
    name=$line    
    echo $name | python -m json.tool >> ~/formatted_search_result.log
done < ~/search_result.log
```

Since, writing to a temp file and then reading from the temp file to format the json hits the performance, looking for some efficient way of doing this.

The expected output is, 
 When i search for

> grep -i "baskar" test.log

,

```
{
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar",
      "reqId": "1",
      "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
    }
  }
  {
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar",
      "reqId": "3",
      "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
    }
```

}

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: Have updated the post with he expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`jq`](http://stedolan.github.com/jq). Given your sample text:

```
sed 's/.*Service - //' file | jq -s .
```

Remove the `-s` option if you don't want an array of objects.

---

You can filter the input to jq:

```
sed -n '/baskar/ s/.*Service - //p' file | jq  .
```

or let jq to the filtering

```
sed 's/.*Service - //' file | jq  'select(.header.user == "baskar")'
```

Either option produces

```
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar",
    "reqId": "1",
    "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
  }
}
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar",
    "reqId": "3",
    "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My requirement is to get only the matching json to be formatted and written to a file. So, when i search for grep -i "baskar" test.log, the out put should be 

{
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar",
      "reqId": "1",
      "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
    }
  }

{
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar",
      "reqId": "3",
      "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
    }
  }

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works awesome. 
Is there anyway to use &.  I tried the below things, but it does not work.
sed -n '/\(baskar\&3\)/ s/.*Service - //p' file | jq  .

This should return only,  
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar",
    "reqId": "3",
    "time": "2015 06:06:13 PM EDT"
  }
}

Comment: I assume you want to match the `reqId` == 3, not any timestamp that has a 3 in it. I'd suggest: `sed 's/.*Service - //' file | jq  'select(.header.user == "baskar" and .header.reqId == "3")'`

Comment: Hi, I have a different scenario now. There are multiple header aka child json elements in a single json, say parent json, and also there is a common header for each such parent json. There are n number of parent json in a file. I would like to search for a string against the child json and the matching child json should be returned along with the parent json header. I dont find this in the JQ example.

Comment: Please ask a new question

Comment: Thanks. Have created a different thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761327/jq-unix-shell-scripting

Comment: Hi Glenn, Could you please reply to the new thread? I tried JQ filtering and unable to achieve what i am looking for.

Comment: Nope, not that strong with jq. Study the tutorial and manual at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ -- Good luck.