# jq - extracting a subset of matching documents from a stream

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq

I have the following JSON message. This is a single complete message. There are so many messages like this in a single file. This json message was generated from a unformated json message using jq.

```
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar"
  },
  "requests": [
    {
      "first_name": "mike",
      "last_name": "mat"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "mike",
      "last_name": "mat"
    }
  ],
  "check": [
    "Y"
  ]
}
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar"
  },
  "message": {
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar"
    },
    "response": {
      "resultsList": {
        "result": [
          {
            "first_name": "mike1",
            "last_name": "mat"
          }
        ]
      },
      "errorMsg": null
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to do some filtering on this. For example, when i search for first_name, mike1, I should get the header and the matching request inside request. Also the matching result inside the Response message. So, the output is expected as follows for the search string mike1.

```
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar"
  },
  "requests": [
    {
      "first_name": "mike1",
      "last_name": "mat"
    }
  ],
  "check": [
    "Y"
  ]
}
{
  "header": {
    "user": "baskar"
  },
  "message": {
    "header": {
      "user": "baskar"
    },
    "response": {
      "resultsList": {
        "result": [
          {
            "first_name": "mike1",
            "last_name": "mat"
          }
        ]
      },
      "errorMsg": null
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, i want to filter out unmatched request inside the requests array and unmatched result inside the result array.

Currently, I use the following script to get the formatted json message from the unformatted json message log file.

```
 sed -n "/<SEARCH_STRING>/ s/.*Service - //p" $1/test.log* | jq . > ~/result.log
```

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Comment: What is `$2`? How does that `sed` script relate to the output you've shown  us? Why are you massaging the data with `sed` before giving it to `jq`?

Comment: Hi, Actually the log file will have many json messages. I use sed to filter out the matching json messages and will remove the unwanted text from the json message since it is appended with date and time in the logs.

Comment: You are already using `jq` to work with your data why not just have it do the filtering correctly instead of hoping that `sed` can get it right?

Comment: There are n number of requests( json ) and there are multiple sub request in each request. My requirement is to match the given string against the sub request and return the main request header and the matched sub request. Am not sure how to achieve this using JQ.

Comment: Note that having a comma just before a close brace is invalid JSON. Also, you don't have enough close braces. Fix these problems.

Comment: Am sorry, have corrected the message now.

Comment: Filtering out the date and time prefix (even if this text is not in JSON form) is also possible with jq (particularly easily if the format is one-JSON-document-per-line), but should probably be asked about in a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq --arg key first_name \
   --arg value mike1 \
   'select(.message.response.resultsList.result[]?[$key]==$value) | .message' \
   <in.json
```

...returns only message content where the result list contains at least one `first_name` of `mike1`.